# Get .nuspec file for existing nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Is there a way to get the original .[nuspec manifest](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference) file for an exiting nuget package?

Let's say I have downloaded a nuget package from the nuget gallery and I am curious how the original .nuspec file looked like to understand how it works. Is there a way to get it out of the package? Or would I need to contact the package creator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot get the original .nuspec file used to generate the .nupkg from the .nupkg file itself, it will be incomplete. The .nupkg file will only contain the metadata for the NuGet package in its .nuspec file even though the original .nuspec had more information in it.

The .nupkg is just a .zip file so you can rename it to .zip or just open it in your favourite Zip File Editor.

If you are interested in the files section of the .nuspec then you would need to find the original .nuspec file from the NuGet package creator. Also if the package creator used `NuGet pack projectname.csproj` then it could still not have the full information about the files since this information is taken from the project file.

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot.

Comment: True, but once check this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42681169/3531672 (in case it helps)

Comment: @DanLeksell - The .nuspec file you get from the .nupkg is incomplete. It misses the metadata section. The first statement is incorrect in my comment is incorrect I will update - the rest should still be correct.

Comment: Actually re-read it. You cannot get the original .nuspec from the .nupkg it will be missing metadata - this is accurate. I have changed it to maybe be more clear.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

1. Open the package using the Nuget Package Explorer:https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer
2. Export the package to a folder as shown
   [image: Nuget Package Explorer]
3. Find the nuspec file in the exported folder.

Answer (score 2):

The nuspec file is inside the package. As @MattWard States .nupkg is just a .zip file so you can rename it to .zip or just open it in your favorite Zip File Editor.

In alot of cases nuspec is contained in the package so you can just:

1. Rename from .nupkg to .Zip
2. Extract files to a location
3. Inside that location should contain the original .nuspec

Inside the Nuget Package Zip Contain the Original Nuspec